# Does intercession of the saints presuppose that saints are omniscient?

Tags: catholicism, saint, intercession-of-saints, omniscience

If we ask a saint to intercede for us, are we not presupposing that the saint is omniscient enough to read our thoughts and to hear our prayers? Doesn't the act of prayer to a saint then contain an implicit confession that the saint is omniscient?

Comment: Omniscience seems a bit of an overkill for the saints simply being aware that they were being prayed to.

Comment: @disciple Exactly. I've never understood how being transported from earth to heaven means that now when people ask you to pray for them, you must have knowledge of all things.

Answer (score 1):

See St. Thomas Aquinas answer to the question "[Whether separated souls know that takes place on earth?](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP089.html#FPQ89A8THEP1)" ([*Summa Theologica* I q. 89 a. 8](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP089.html#FPQ89A8THEP1)), who writes that St. Gregory the Great's opinion "seems to be the more probable one", namely

> that the souls of the blessed who see God do know all that passes here [on earth]. For they are equal to the angels, of whom Augustine says that they know what happens among those living on earth.

Viz., since the angels know what happens on earth, and the souls who behold the beatific vision are like angels, then it seems that those souls also know what happens on earth, which would include intercessory prayers.

Comment: This is probably moot since the question is closed as a duplicate, but would this just be an awareness of the things that any observer could see happening, or would it also include our inner thoughts, even those one would not want a saint to know?